# Access to the path 'path' is denied while ziping a folder in C drive

Tags: c#, zip

Currently I am facing a problem while ziping a folder using `System.IO.Compression`'s `ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory()`. Please see the attachment as the example of my codes:

```
string startLoc = zipFolderSource_txt.Text;
string zipLoc = zipFileLoaction_txt.Text + @"\backup_" + DateTime.Now.ToString() + ".zip";
ZipFile.CreateFromDirectory(startLoc, zipLoc);
File.Delete(vdspcFormatDataSource_txt.Text);
```

and the string being passed into `startLoc` is `C:\Users\WayneLee\Desktop\Test2`
as for `zipLoc` is `C:\Users\WayneLee\Desktop\Gen2`

I have search through the web and I couldn't find an effective solution for this particular problem.

Comment: Could the source folder be in use somewhere?

Comment: Can you elaborate your question further?

Comment: If source folder is in use while to try to create the file it might do a conflict (could also be if you are in the midst of creating the folder and already using it)
is there a process/other thread/other task involved?

Comment: The folder is not in use while I zipping it, as all of my processes in this project are not running simultaneously.

Comment: I have had a few interractions with ``C:\`` where the drive has R/W protection unless you have administrator acces, this could be a case of inssuficient permissions in your application, or that it is in use, but I think you should try with administrative permissions to your app, either by adding a manifest or right clicking the exe and selecting run as administrator.

Comment: And this code is not running in a thread/ task?

Comment: @SimpleCoder I was thinking likewise, then I tried to run as administrator on the application. And the error still persists.

Comment: @DaniToker Nope.

Comment: @WayneLee could you give me the exact input being taken from the textboxes?

Comment: @WayneLee DateTime has illegal characters and cannot create a file with ``:`` For me it throws an exception: ```Unhandled exception. System.IO.IOException: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect. : 'C:\Temp\backup_27.03.2022 12:49:58.zip'``` Replace ``:`` with ``.`` using regex or remove it completely

Comment: @SimpleCoder let me update in the question

Comment: ```string currentTimeStamp = DateTime.Now.ToString();
string currentTimeStampReplaced = currentTimeStamp.Replace(":", ".");``` here this should do it.

Comment: @SimpleCoder I have tried your solution, but it returns another error stated that the access is denied for the value I passed in the startLoc, you can refer to the amended post for further reference.

Comment: Now I noticed something even interesting, even though an error of "Access is denied" is returned, but the Zip file still can be created.

Comment: The best practice is to handle the `exception` and report the details of the exception, then you will be able to find the root cause yourself. Embed your code that calls CreateFromDirectory inside a `try...catch` block. In your case, what is the program that is executing this piece of code -  does it run with logged in user's credentials - the `Desktop` and `My Documents` are _special folders_ that are only accessible to that specific user, if the running program is under another user principal, then those paths are not accessible to that program.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran thanks for the advice, will definitely try it out